# How to concatenate a row of values into 1 single string of text?

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation

I'm a novice to VBA in Excel, but I'm trying to concatenate all of the values in row of data into one text string and I am having trouble figuring it out. I have been trying For-Next loops and Do Until loops to capture each cell value up to the bottom of the row, and then concatenate it (with spaces in between) into a single cell that I can copy and paste the data out of. Thanks in advance for your help!

```
Sub String_Acct_Numbers()

Dim AccountNumber As String
Dim StartRow As Integer
Dim NumRows As Integer

NumRows = Range("A1", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

For StartRow = 2 To NumRows

AccountNumber = Cells(StartRow, 1).Value & " " & Cells(StartRow + 1, 
1).Value

Next StartRow

Range("C1") = AccountNumber


End Sub
```

Comment: Your code looks a bit strange. It does not even compile for me. One row is highlighted in red as a problem. Can you post a data sample and the expected result? As a new user, please read this: edit you post to provide these details, then post a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is 100% correct, use `TEXTJOIN` if you have it available.  If you don't have it available then you can use this ...

```
Public Function ConcatenateCells(ByVal rngCells As Range, Optional ByVal strDelimiter As String = " ") As String
    Dim objCell As Range

    For Each objCell In rngCells
        If ConcatenateCells <> "" Then ConcatenateCells = ConcatenateCells & strDelimiter
        ConcatenateCells = ConcatenateCells & objCell.Text
    Next
End Function
```

... you can reference that function directly from a cell, easier than running a macro to update a cell and yes, there are a heap of different implementations already documented but if you're not going to go searching, the above will give you what you want.

Answer (score -1):

If you have Office 365 or Excel 2019 this can be done without VBA, using the [TextJoin](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) function.

If you don't have any of these Excel versions, please use one of the multitudes of VBA codes that have been published on the web over the last 20 years to concatenate ranges.